# Translation for "calificador" (from Spanish to English)

Tags: meaning, translation

In Spanish, ***calificador*** means someone (or something) that examines some score or performance and gives you a grade or a score.

Wich is the best and commonly used term? I've found this one:

**grader**: *a person or thing that grades*

But I'm not sure if is the correct use in this context:

"There's a part of the system that calculates what's the user score, this calculation is performed by a ***Grader*** object which will output none, bronze, silver or gold"

Comment: You most likely need a wording specific to a situation.  You should give a context in which you need to use a term for this.

Comment: I've added a context. Hope it will help to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a common English word that includes both the idea of a teacher giving grades and a contest judge giving scores.

You used the word "judge" in your question, and in general someone who gives a score in a contest is called a "judge".

A person who keeps track of scores is called a "scorekeeper". But normally we don't use scorekeeper for someone who decides what your score should be, but just for the person who writes it down on a piece of paper or types it into the computer.

"Grader" is, I think, pretty rarely used. And in any case I've only heard it used for someone who grades school assignments, not for someone who assigns scores in a contest. Generally we just call the person who grades school assignments a "teacher". The title is understood to include the job of grading assignments.

There are words that you could use, like "assessor" or "evaluator". But the examples I can think of are obscure and have rather vague meanings. They could mean what you want, but they could also have other meanings depending on context.

If you need a word to include both ideas -- grading school papers and scoring contests --you could, of course, use an obscure word or make up a word. In either case, be sure to tell your readers what you are using it to mean.

Otherwise, you need to use a longer phrase, like "people who grade school assignments or judge contests".

Comment: I've removed the examples of the teacher and the judge. I'm not looking a word for that specific examples, I'm looking for a more general use of the action of "giving grades" to someone.

Comment: If this is a video game and you're talking about evaluating an athletic performance, I'd say "judge". If you're talking about evaluating a quiz, then "grader" or "scorer" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

"Evaluator" fits better, because it can be a person or entity that measures performance across a wider range of domains.